# How use Group by and Max(date) multi record

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, group-by, max

i want Group by by Max(Datetime) each record. but i query have dupplicatate record. i want don't duplicate record.

SQL:

```
select   a.pmn_code,
           a.ref_period,
           a.SERVICE_TYPE,
           min(a.status) keep (dense_rank last order by a.updated_dtm) as status,
           max(a.updated_dtm) as updated_dtm
  from     tempChkStatus a
  group by a.pmn_code, a.ref_period, a.SERVICE_TYPE
```

**Data Table tempChkStatus:**

```
PMN_CODE | REF_PERIOD  | SERVICE_TYPE    | STATUS | UPDATED_DTM
A        | 01/2016     | OI              | I      | 19/08/2016 10:54:44
A        | 01/2016     | OP              | N      | 06/06/2017 15:09:55
A        | 02/2016     | OT              | I      | 31/08/2016 08:37:45
A        | 02/2016     | OT              | N      | 12/10/2016 11:13:56
A        | 04/2016     | OI              | I      | 19/08/2016 10:54:44
A        | 04/2016     | OP              | N      | 06/06/2017 15:09:55
```

Result SQL:

```
PMN_CODE | REF_PERIOD  | SERVICE_TYPE    | STATUS | UPDATED_DTM
A        | 01/2016  | OI        | I  | 19/08/2016 10:54:44
A        | 01/2016  | OP        | N  | 06/06/2017 15:09:55
A        | 02/2016  | OT        | N  | 12/10/2016 11:13:56
A        | 04/2016  | OI        | I  | 19/08/2016 10:54:44
A        | 04/2016  | OP        | N  | 06/06/2017 15:09:55
```

**But I want Result:**

```
PMN_CODE | REF_PERIOD  | SERVICE_TYPE    | STATUS | UPDATED_DTM
A        | 01/2016     | OP              | N      | 06/06/2017 15:09:55
A        | 02/2016     | OT              | N      | 12/10/2016 11:13:56
A        | 04/2016     | OP              | N      | 06/06/2017 15:09:55
```

Help me please. Thanks advance ;)

Comment: Those aren't duplicates. You have one row for each permutation of `a.pmn_code, a.ref_period, a.SERVICE_TYPE` . If that's not what you want you have a business rule missing from your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with tempChkStatus (

PMN_CODE, REF_PERIOD  , SERVICE_TYPE    , STATUS , UPDATED_DTM) as
(
select 'A',         '01/2016'      ,'OI',              'I',      to_date('19/08/2016 10:54:44', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 'A',         '01/2016'      ,'OP',              'N',      to_date('06/06/2017 15:09:55', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 'A',         '02/2016'      ,'OT',              'I',      to_date('31/08/2016 08:37:45', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 'A',         '02/2016'      ,'OT',              'N',      to_date('12/10/2016 11:13:56', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 'A',         '04/2016'      ,'OI',              'I',      to_date('19/08/2016 10:54:44', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
select 'A',         '04/2016'      ,'OP',              'N',      to_date('06/06/2017 15:09:55', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual 
)
select * from (
select e.*, max(updated_dtm) over (partition by ref_period) md from tempchkstatus e 
)
where updated_dtm = md
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `SERVICE_TYPE` from the `GROUP BY`:

```
select s.pmn_code, s.ref_period,
       min(s.SERVICE_TYPE) as service_type,
       min(s.status) keep (dense_rank last order by s.updated_dtm) as status,
       max(s.updated_dtm) as updated_dtm
from tempChkStatus s
group by s.pmn_code, s.ref_period;
```

The `GROUP BY` expressions define the rows returns by an aggregation query.

This version uses `MIN()` on `SERVICE_TYPE`.  It is not clear what logic you want for the result set.

Comment: maybe `keep (dense_rank last order by s.updated_dtm)`after `max(s.SERVICE_TYPE)`